# How do I write glimmer aware ember application?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli

I am writing a new big project with ember latest version and I don't get any deprecation in console. does that means it will work without major change for glimmer release.

Is there any design patterns or best practices should i follow to ensure it will work without any change after glimmer release ? (I know only DDAU( data down and actions up principle) )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you talk about *Glimmer2*, because the current ember rendering engine *is* already Glimmer.

And you don't have to do anything specific. Just keep away from private API's.

As long you just use public API's Glimmer2 should just drop in, as well as Glimmer1 did. Glimmer2 is (probably) not a breaking change, so even deprecations of public API's should not break it. Still try to avoid any deprecations.

Comment: Yes. It should just change under the hood and you shouldn't have to do anything.